# Laravel query where subquery

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am looking for the best way to perform the query below as a `Laravel 4.2` *query*.  I am struggling on the `where` clause which has a sub *query* to work.

What my *query* is doing:
I have a parent table with a `1-many` child table.  I want to get a list of all the child records associated to the parent record only knowing a current child record.

```
select child.id, child.jobNumber
from child
where child.parentId = (select child.parentId from child where child.id = 2)
order by child.jobNumber, child.id
```

Something like:

```
$query = DB::table('child');
$query->select(array('child.id','child.jobNumber'));
$query->orderBy('child.jobNumber');
$query->orderBy('child.id');

// how do I do my where clause?

$list = $query->get();
```

Comment: Are you using Eloquent?

Comment: I am, but for this, I would prefer to just do a query.

Comment: This will be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064678/laravel-eloquent-subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using `whereRaw`?  http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

```
$query = DB::table('child');
$query->select(array('child.id','child.jobNumber'));
$query->whereRaw('child.parentId = (select child.parentId from child where child.id = 2)');
$query->orderBy('child.jobNumber');
$query->orderBy('child.id');

// how do I do my where clause?

$list = $query->get();
```