# how to convert sql query to eloquent laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, code-conversion

how to convert simple mysql query to eloquent laravel?

in fact I want to convert down query :

```
 SELECT temp.* FROM
(SELECT * FROM avilableproducts ORDER BY avilableproducts.count DESC) AS temp
GROUP BY temp.products_id, temp.color
HAVING temp.products_id = 27
ORDER BY temp.count DESC;
```

to

```
$Avilableproducts = $Avilableproducts->select(DB::raw('temp.*'))
        ->from(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM avilableproducts ORDER BY count DESC) AS temp'))
        ->groupBy(['products_id', 'color'])
        ->orderBy('count', 'desc');
```

Comment: May this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/27066395/4916265