# How can I do this SQL in Query builder laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

How can I do this SQL in Query builder laravel

```
select Doctor_id from doctors where Doctor_id NOT IN
 (SELECT Doctor_id from report_reviewers WHERE Report_id = 26 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
$result = DB::table('doctors')
->whereNotIn('doctor_id', function($q){
    $q->from('report_reviewers')
    ->select('Doctor_id')
    ->where('Report_id', '=', 26)
})
->select('doctor_id')
->get();
```

Whenver in doubt, if you know the raw SQL, you can simply do

```
$query = 'select Doctor_id from doctors ...';
$result = DB::select($query);
```

Also, all credit goes to this genius [How to create a subquery using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064678/how-to-create-a-subquery-using-laravel-eloquent)

**Update**

The missing argument comes from the closure you are using

```
->whereNotIn('doctor_id', function($q,$id){ 
    $q->from('report_reviewers') 
    ->select('Doctor_id') 
    ->where('Report_id',$id); 
})
```

You need to pass the `$id` variable like this

```
->whereNotIn('doctor_id', function($q) use ($id) { 
    $q->from('report_reviewers') 
    ->select('Doctor_id') 
    ->where('Report_id',$id); 
})
```

Try again and see.

Comment: what about this :
        $result = DB::table('doctors')
            ->join('users', 'doctors.UserID', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('doctors.Acceptable',1)
            ->whereNotIn('doctor_id', function($q,$id){
                $q->from('report_reviewers')
                    ->select('Doctor_id')
                    ->where('Report_id',$id);
                })
            ->select('doctors.doctor_id','users.name')
            ->get();

missing in argument 2  ($id)

Comment: Oh never mind. You are ungrateful. My code worked, you accepted my answer. Now you require further assistance, you unaccept my answer even though it worked. All good, have a nice day.

Comment: thanks EddyTheDove for help me about your answer edit for this 
        $this->xx = $id;
        $result = DB::table('doctors')
            ->join('users', 'doctors.UserID', '=', 'users.id')
            ->where('doctors.Acceptable',1)
            ->whereNotIn('doctor_id', function($q){
                $q->from('report_reviewers')
                    ->select('Doctor_id')
                    ->where('Report_id',$this->xx);
                })
            ->select('doctors.doctor_id','users.name')
            ->get();