# How to write this subquery in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have to group by the taken_date year to get the years and in the query I need to get the total work days and count of the order. Currently I am running this in MySQL procedure for executing this, but I sense there will be a better way to handle this, kindly let me know

```
select DATE_FORMAT(taken_date, '%Y') year, count(id) total, sum(total_days) total_days from
                    (
                        select id, taken_date, getNumOfWorkDays(order.order_num) total_days from order
                        where order.is_active = 1 and order.deleted_at is null
                        order by taken_date
                    ) as order_years group by YEAR(taken_date) order by taken_date desc
```

Order Table columns looks like below
[image]

getNumOfWorkDays function will give you only work days based on start and end date of the order uses some other table to know the work days

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064678/how-to-create-a-subquery-using-laravel-eloquent

Comment: I have to tell you its nearly impossible to reconstruct your query without providing the relationships and the tables you have in your database, try to provide your sample database structure and sample data,. Thank You,

Comment: @apelidoko added database table info