# How to convert mysql to query builder in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have this raw query in MySQL I need to translate to laravel 5.5 query builder. Thanks

```
SELECT
group_table.id,
group_table.name,
group_table.description,
GROUP_CONCAT(
    group_table.languageName SEPARATOR ', '
) as languages
FROM
(
    SELECT
        translate_groups.id,
        translate_groups.name,
        translate_groups.description,
        languages.name as languageName
    FROM
        translate_groups
    LEFT JOIN language_translate_group ON
        language_translate_group.translate_group_id = translate_groups.id
    LEFT JOIN languages ON
        language_translate_group.language_id = languages.id
) group_table
GROUP BY
group_table.id,
group_table.name,
group_table.description
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your query so that we may read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a subquery using Laravel Eloquent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064678/how-to-create-a-subquery-using-laravel-eloquent)

Answer (score 0):

you can run any raw query you want in query builder:

```
$queryString = 'WHAT RAW QUERY YOU WANT';
$result = DB::select(DB::raw($queryString));
```

just make use of `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB`;

Comment: I need to translate to laravel 5.5 query builder. ( not collection)