# Where Not In using query builder

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Similary with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27066395) I need to execute the following Sql query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from table where column NOT IN (SELECT table2.id from table2 where table2.someanothercolumn >0 );
```

Using Eloquent's query builder, therefore I tried the following (Model `Table` maps into table `table` and Model `TableTwo` maps into table `table2`):

```
$enties = Table::where('id',function($q){
  $q->from('table2')->select('id')->where('someanothercolumn','>',0);
})->count();
```

But on the cide above how I can Place the `NOT IN` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **answer** is in the following snippet of code:

```
$enties = Table::whereNotIn('id',function($q){
  $q->from('table2')->select('id')->where('someanothercolumn','>',0);
})->count();
```

In other words just use the `whereNotIn`.